# Check if the first 24 values of an array are not empty

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I've an array called `totalist` with a list of some stuff. What I want to do, is for each line of `totalist`to check if the first 24 values are not empty, I dont care the rest ones.

`totalist` contains lines with something like:

```
totalist = [
    ['stuff1', '33.0', '5.0', '165.0', '6.0', '990.0', '880.0', '95.0', '19.0', '3135.0', '4.0', '0.666666666667', '3.83333333333', '330.0', '9.5', '4.75', '3.16666666667', '225.0', '13.9333333333', '6.96666666667', '15.6666666667', '4.64444444444', 'cba', '0.1', '', '', 'test', '40.0', '3.0', '120.0', '4.0', '480.0', '480.0', '24.0', '8.0', '960.0', '', '0.0', '2.0', 'testing', '0.1', '', '', '', 'asdf', '2034', '123', '34', '23', '4', '56', 'asd', 'ok', 'cruz', 'reti', 'clip', 'twp', 'three', 'pedr', 'dcheck', '1-4'],
    ['stuff2', '40.0', '3.0', '120.0', '5.0', '600.0', '552.0', '24.0', '8.0', '960.0', '2.0', '0.4', '2.0', '200.0', '4.8', '2.4', '1.6', '200.0', '4.8', '2.4', '2.0', '1.6', 'qw', '0.1', '', '', 'Mec', '34.0', '6.0', '204.0', '4.0', '816.0', '714.0', '75.0', '12.5', '2550.0', '2.0', '0.5', '3.625', '123', '0.1', '', '123', 'vve', '', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '8.0', '6.0', '4.0', '4.0', '6.0', '6.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0'],
    ['stuff3 ', '34.0', '6.0', '204.0', '6.0', '1224.0', '1156.0', '75.0', '12.5', '3840.0', '2.0', '0.333333333333', '3.47058823529', '600.0', '6.4', '3.2', '2.13333333333', '190.0', '20.2105263158', '10.1052631579', '33.173374613', '6.73684210526', 'rem', '0.1', '', '', 'tapa', '24.0', '8.0', '192.0', '4.0', '768.0', '672.0', '73.0', '9.125', '1752.0', '2.0', '0.5', '2.78125', 'hem', '0.1', '', '', 'sock', '3.0', '', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '8.0', '6.0', '4.0', '4.0', '6.0', '6.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0'],
]
```

So for example, in the first line, I want to check if the values from `stuff1` to `0.1` are not empty.

What I'm trying to iterate by using xrange:

```
for i in xrange(len(totalist)):
    print totalist[i]
```

That prints me all the lines, but Im stuck when I have iterate every line from 0 to 23. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for elem in totallist:
    print all(elem[:24])  # first 24 elements are non-empty.
```

Answer (score 1):

`xrange()` returns a list of items, that you have defined to analyse each list of your array; you could use it to pass over the 24 first elements of each list:

```
for sublist in totalist:
    for i in xrange(24):
        print sublist[i]!=""
```

But, all in all, four each line you could do it with function `all`:

```
for sublist in totalist:
    print all( elem!="" for elem in sublist[1:25] )
```

Comment: To be precise, xrange() returns an xrange object which is basically a generator that iterates through a list of numbers in the specified range. range() in the other hand, does indeed return a list of integers (not any items).

Comment: That's the more-correct, long-version answer, thanks for the precision!

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize a flag array  of size len(totalist) and initialize it to 24 assuming all values are initially filled.

While deleting some value in first 24 you can decrement that flag and inserting in first 24 you increment it.

Then you can simply check the contents of flag to check whether first 24 are empty or not in O(1) time. Hope it helps.